# cpp SOCK_RAW continua recibiendo el mismo mensaje ad infinitum

Tags: c++, socket

creo un socket de la forma:

```
fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_RAW, IPPROTO_UDP);
```

despues procedo:

```
bind(fd, (struct sockaddr*)&saddr, sizeof(struct sockaddr_in))
```

donde saddr admite INADDR_ANY y es de la familia AF_INET

El problema que tengo es que despues al escuchar con un bucle del tipo:

```
while(true) {
  char mess[BUFFSIZE+1];
  int content_size = recv(fd, mess, BUFFSIZE, 0);
  mess[content_size] = '\0';
  std::cout<<"recibí el mensaje: "<<mess<<std::endl;
}
```

Una vez recibo un mensaje continúo recibiéndolo durante todos los posteriores recorridos del bucle

EDIT: programo en DEBIAN.

Comment: ¿Estás programando en plataforma windows?

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster No, Debian.

Comment: Entiendo que después de llamar a `bind` haces un `listen` y después un `accept` ¿no? Estás omitiendo ese código... lo mismo estás escuchando por la conexión del `connect` en vez de por la conexión del `accept`...

Comment: @eferion no, no hago listen ni accept.

Comment: ¿Has probado limpiar `mess` a cada vuelta del bucle? ¿has comprobado que el retorno de `recv` no sea `-1`?

Answer (score 0):

Estás configurando la conexión con UDP, es decir, con datagramas:

```
fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_RAW, IPPROTO_UDP);
//                             ^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Para este tipo de conexión debes usar `recvfrom`. Algo así:

```
struct sockaddr_storage addr;
int content_size = recvfrom(fd, mess, BUFFSIZE, 0, (struct sockaddr*)&addr, sizeof(struct sockaddr_storage));
```